# Deploying axis2.war to container broke client calls to external axis2 webservices

Tags: java, apache-axis, resin

I have several existing web-apps deployed as standalone war files in the app container (resin). Some use axis2 jar files and axis2-generated Stub files to make calls to external SOAP based web services. They were all working fine prior to this.

I recently deployed axis2.war to the same container in order to create web services (unrelated to the client code mentioned above).

As soon as I restart the app container, client calls to the external webservices seem to be "intercepted" by my newly deployed axis2.war. 
Services appear temporarily in the "Available Services" page of the axis2 web-app, with what appears to be randomly generated name based on the original external webservice name.

These services disappear shortly after, but the result is that my client code fails with a 500 error, as the local Axis2.war doesnt know how to handle those requests.

I have been searching for 2 days and haven't found mention of anyone experiencing anything similar. I am not even sure how to explain what is going on, as my client code never references localhost to make those web service calls. I am assuming this has to do with some configuration in axis2.war?

If anyone has any idea or insight into what might be happening, I would really appreciate any information.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Do you mean that axis2.war interferes with the calls in clients for external WebServices (not in the same container)?

Comment: That's correct. The client apps make calls to WebServices that are on remote containers not hosted by us, but somehow those calls are being intercepted by the axis2.war running on our container where the client apps are hosted.

Comment: Does anybody have any idea what is going on ?